# Free Hosting Awardspace - Remote file calling via PHP

Tags: php, function

Awardspace being a big host free...services does seem to block all remote calls via PHP to scripts or even feeds to be called in my PHP Script

What other alternatives I can use on Awardspace...does anyones have alternative to remote file funcitons ( curl , fsockopen , fopen , readfile , file_get_contents) to be used on Awardspace free hosting

Answer (score 0):

If they want to block access to outside resources, and they're any good at their job, they have not left any alternatives open.

(You can test for the existence of `curl` and `fsockopen` functions of course.)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but it's not worth wasting your time. Even if you do this - you would get banned eventually. Buy real payed hosting (1-5$/mo) without these annoying limits and more reliability.

Answer (score 0):

i friend of mine once had the same problem. they blocked external opening functions but they left shell execution functions working ;)
so system("wget ...") did the job :D 
but bars is right, you should really considering paying some few dollars for professional hosting